# Counting values in an employee dictionary database in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, counter, key-value

python is  new language for me so this question might sound simple, but if someone can point me in the right direction, I would appreciate it! I created a dictionary call employees and it holds some value about them:

I'm trying to read how many people are in each department, for example: tech-2, accounting-1.

I have something like this, but it prints out blank.

```
  def main():
   employees= {'name': 'John', 'empID': '102', 'dpt': 'tech', 'title': 
   'programmer', 'salary': '75'}
   {'name': 'Jane', 'empID': '202', 'dpt': 'tech', 'title': 'programmer', 
   'salary': '80'}
   {'name': 'Joe', 'empID': '303', 'dpt': 'accounting', 'title': 
   'accountant', 'salary': '85'}
    for item in employees:
    dic = employees[item]
    if dic['dpt'[0]]==dic['dpt'[1]]:
        duplicate += 1
        print("there are "+ duplicate)
    else:
        print("There are no duplicate")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to import `Counter`, use a dictionary to keep track of the employee count per department:

```
employee_list = [{
    'name': 'John',
    'empID': '102',
    'dpt': 'tech',
    'title': 'programmer',
    'salary': '75'
}, {
    'name': 'Jane',
    'empID': '202',
    'dpt': 'tech',
    'title': 'programmer',
    'salary': '80'
}, {
    'name': 'Joe',
    'empID': '303',
    'dpt': 'accounting',
    'title': 'accountant',
    'salary': '85'
}]

department_to_count = dict()
for employee in employee_list:
    department = employee["dpt"]

    if department not in department_to_count:
        department_to_count[department] = 0

    department_to_count[department] += 1

for department, employee_count in department_to_count.items():
    print("Department {} has {} employees".format(department,
                                                  employee_count))
```

Comment: Thanks, I used your logic and changed some things a bit and it worked!

Answer (score 2):

Use [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
from collections import Counter

employees = [{'name': 'John', 'empID': '102', 'dpt': 'tech', 'title': 'programmer', 'salary': '75'},
             {'name': 'Jane', 'empID': '202', 'dpt': 'tech', 'title': 'programmer', 'salary': '80'},
             {'name': 'Joe', 'empID': '303', 'dpt': 'accounting', 'title': 'accountant', 'salary': '85'}]

dpts = [x['dpt'] for x in employees]
print(Counter(dpts))

# Counter({'tech': 2, 'accounting': 1})
```

Comment: for extracting usable dictionary out of Counter of object you can do `dict(Counter(dpts))`

Comment: @MigratedPigeon, Can you explain in what way `Counter` is *not* a usable dictionary? It has some modifications and additional methods, but for a dictionary used for counting I'd class these as *enhancements*.

Comment: @Austin Thanks! I'll have to use this next time. I changed my program slightly to include user input and went with a different logic.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
def main():
    duplicate = 0
    employees = [
        {'name': 'John', 'empID': '102', 'dpt': 'tech', 'title': 'programmer', 'salary': '75'},
        {'name': 'Jane', 'empID': '202', 'dpt': 'tech', 'title': 'programmer', 'salary': '80'},
        {'name': 'Joe', 'empID': '303', 'dpt': 'accounting', 'title': 'accountant', 'salary': '85'}
    ]
    tech_dep = 0
    accounting_dep = 0
    for item in employees:
        if item['dpt'] == 'tech':
            tech_dep += 1
        elif item['dpt'] == 'accounting':
            accounting_dep += 1

    print('Number of Employees from tech dep are : ', tech_dep)
    print('Number of Employees from accounting dep are : ', accounting_dep)


main()
```

**It will give you output like this:**

```
Number of Employees from tech dep are :  2
Number of Employees from accounting dep are :  1
```

**Note:**

It is a simple answer to your question because as you said that you are new to python so i just thought to give you simple answer! Also note that the way you create dictionary in your question is wrong you can either make dictionary of dictionary or list of dictionaries. Moreover, the answer @Austin just gave you is also simple and it shows the use of counter.

Hope this will help you! :)

Comment: Thanks! Your answer helped me see the breakdown if I want something simple, but it's not very dynamic. Good to know, though.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for one specific key's total, you can use the `.count()` [list method](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/datastructures.html) as a direct query.

Given a list of dicts:

```
>>> employees = [{'name': 'John', 'empID': '102', 'dpt': 'tech', 'title': 'programmer', 'salary': '75'},
         {'name': 'Jane', 'empID': '202', 'dpt': 'tech', 'title': 'programmer', 'salary': '80'},
         {'name': 'Joe', 'empID': '303', 'dpt': 'accounting', 'title': 'accountant', 'salary': '85'}]
```

You can create a list of each with a list comprehension:

```
>>> [d['dpt'] for d in employees]
['tech', 'tech', 'accounting']
```

And that can then be tallied:

```
>>> [d['dpt'] for d in employees].count('tech')
2
>>> [d['dpt'] for d in employees].count('accounting')
1
>>> [d['dpt'] for d in employees].count('nothing')
0
```

Alternatively, you can construct a generator that will tally specific values:

```
>>> sum(1 for d in employees if d['dpt']=='tech')
2
```

If you want to have the count of all elements (other than using a Counter) you can do:

```
>>> lot=[d['dpt'] for d in employees]
>>> {c:lot.count(c) for c in set(lot)}
{'accounting': 1, 'tech': 2}
```